# Expansion of two-dimensional array in c++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array

I have a question.
If I read the txt file
As follows:

> 12.5,14.8,17.4
>
> 21.6,25.9,32.4
>
> 27.8,36.2,45.1
>
> 23.8,28.6,40.5

I read values ​​to be stored in a two-dimensional array of a `2 x 3`

How do I use C++11 write

I originally `2 x 3` two-dimensional array can grow to `4 x 3` array

How to write the array can grow the number of rows

When I originally array full

And the data values ​​are complete in the new, larger array

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

according to http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/EzywvCM9/

"C++11 provides std::array, which has the purpose of replacing C arrays. It is a fixed-sized, lightweight alternative to the dynamically-sized std::vector."

emphasis on the 'fixed-sized'. so i guess, you'd have to create a bigger array and copy the entries into the new array.

more details here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Answer (score 0):

Re-declare an array with the new size and copy the data, or use std::vector

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the array changes, don't use an array. Instead use `std::vector`, which can grow dynamically. In case of a two dimensional data structure, use a vector of vectors. In C++11ish pseudocode:

```
using namespace std;

vector<vector<double> > data;
vector<double> dataLine;

vector<double>* readDataLine(istream file) {
    vector<double>* line = new vector<double>;
    for (each row...) {
         double value;
         file >> value;
         line->append(value);
    }
    return line;
}

void readFile() {
    for (each line...) {
         vector<double>* line = readLine(someFileStream)
         data.append(line);
    }

    // access a single element like in an array:
    double element = data[lineNo][rowNo];
}
```